# when i'm using NotificationListener then RefreshIndicator is not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use RefreshIndicator with NotificationListener but it is not working.

Basically I want pagination & pull to refresh both working on same screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show relevant code so we can assist.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically have to put the `RefreshIndicator` inside the `NotificationListener`.

**Example:**

```
return NotificationListener<ScrollEndNotification>(
  onNotification: (scrollEnd) {
    final metrics = scrollEnd.metrics;
    if (metrics.atEdge) {
      bool isTop = metrics.pixels == 0;
      if (!isTop) {
        loadMessages();
      }
    }
    return true;
  },
  child: RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: () async => setFutures(),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: MessagesFeed(
        loadMore: loadMessages,
        key: _messageFeedKey,
        messages: snapshot.data!,
        answers: false,
        messageId: -1,
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```